# Nested attributes with another constant attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have the following models: `Project` and `Task`. I use nested attributes as follows:

```
<% form_for @project, :url => consultant_report_path(@project), :html => { :method => :put} do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :tasks do |builder| %>
    <%= render "due_dates_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= submit_tag %></p>
<% end %>
```

And I have tasks type.

How can I make this code only for tasks with `type='economical'` for example?

Comment: I don'y really understand your question but why don't you filter tis in the partial with a `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can accomplish this in many ways:

Filtering object:

```
<% f.fields_for :tasks do |builder| %>
  <% if builder.object.type == 'economical' %>
    <%= render "due_dates_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Specifying the instance:

```
<% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
  <% if task.type == 'economical' %>
    <% f.fields_for :tasks, task do |builder| %>
      <%= render "due_dates_fields", :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or specifying the collection to be used:

```
<% f.fields_for :tasks, @economical_taks do |builder| %>
  <%= render "due_dates_fields", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

Hoe this helps, look [Fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can make that a custom relationship

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks

  has_many :economical_tasks, :class_name => 'Task',
                              :foreign_key => 'project_id',
                              :conditions => ['tasks.type = ?', 'economical']
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :economical_tasks
end
```

Then your form builder can look like this:

```
<% f.fields_for :economical_tasks do |builder| %>
  <%= render "due_dates_fields", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```